# If $f(x)f'(x)<0$, then is f increasing / decreasing?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let f:R to R be a differentiable function so that $f(x)f'(x)<0$, then which of the following is necessarily true ?

(A) f is an increasing function

(B) f is a decreasing function

(C) |f| is an increasing function

(D) |f| is a decreasing function

f being Differentiable in R to R probably suggests that functions like |x| and 1/x are not applicable here.

Here, there are two possible cases ...

Case 1) f(x) is positive and f'(x) is negative. This implies f is a decreasing function.

Case 2) f(x) is negative and f'(x) is positive. This implies f is an increasing function

Does this mean   |f| is an increasing function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let $g(x) = (f(x))^2 \Rightarrow g'(x) = 2f(x)f'(x) < 0 \Rightarrow g(x)$ is a decreasing function, but $\sqrt{g(x)} = |f(x)|$, thus $|f(x)|$ is a decreasing function. Thus $D)$ is valid.

Comment: Such a nice way to look at the problem .. also by definition, g(x) is positive .. so we can take square root .. Thanks a lot :)